# Omnibus uniform Chef version install across platforms

Tags: bash, scripting, chef

So I'm looking for a uniform way to install chef on a number of different servers running different platforms.  I know I can use the omnibus installer for this, but I also need a way to lock or otherwise keep the versions consistent across machines.  Is there a good way of doing this without having ruby already installed on the machines?

For example, I have two brand new servers with minimal installs.  One has Ubuntu and the other has CentOS.  I order one when Chef 10.12.0 is the latest and the next when 10.14.0 is the latest.  I want a uniform way of installing chef on these machines and making sure that they both have chef 10.12.0 (or whichever version I specify).  Does anyone have any ideas?  Could I just customize the omnibus install script to accept a specific version option?  Or does it already do so?

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer turns out to be rather simple.  The Omnibus script actually takes an argument for the version I want it to install so I can just call the script like so:

`./install.sh -v 10.16.6`